# Using array_walk to alter array values

Tags: php, arrays

Here's the function I'm trying to call on a set of array items:

```
function do_this_stuff( &$key ) {

    $lookups = array(
        'this' => 'that'
    );

    if (array_key_exists($key, $lookups)) {
        return $lookups[$key];
    } else {
        return ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $key));
    }
}
```

And the call to it:

```
array_walk($data[$set][0], 'do_this_stuff');
```

If anything in the `$lookups` array is in the array in param one of array walk, I want to replace its contents. The `do_this_stuff` function works, but nothing I've tried has resulted in the actual input array values updating.

Comment: BTW, what does ELI5 refer to?

Comment: @Barmar: Explain Like I'm Five, probably?

Comment: Yea, explain like I'm five. Sorry guys, too much Reddit.

Comment: Downvoted. Hm. I feel like this is a reasonable question, easily overlooked in the docs. I can't be the only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the updated value back to `$key`, not return it.

```
function do_this_stuff( &$key ) {

    $lookups = array(
        'this' => 'that'
    );

    if (array_key_exists($key, $lookups)) {
        $key = $lookups[$key];
    } else {
        $key = ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Barmar! That did the trick. Kind of renders this function useless though, no? I'm new to these functional paradigms.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that. If you mean that you could do the same thing with a `for` or `foreach` loop, that's true. Sometimes there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: If I wanted to use `do_this_stuff` outside of `array_walk`, I would want the function to return or echo, rather than just set equal to `$key`. Seems like something that just hasn't clicked for me.

Comment: But the reason it takes the argument as a reference is so that it can modify what it was given, rather than return or echo it. You could split it into two functions: one that returns the replacement, and another that calls the first function and modifies its argument with what it returns.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you very much for sticking around and explaining!